# Easiest way to have a text input update live based on another text field?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, user-input, kotlin-android-extensions

I am very very new to Kotlin. I made a calculator app that could only add/subtract/multiply/divide and it was still a bit finicky, that's the extent of my knowledge.

I would like to make a very simple app that convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit, BUT every demo I have seen so far required the user to hit a button after they are done inputting the temperature in order for the conversion to occur.

I'd like to make the app have two text fields, which both update live as the other one is being filled out. This way, the user doesn't need to hit any additional "confirm" button, as the conversion will be done in real-time as text is being entered. And when the user switches to the opposing field, the same is done vice versa.

I'm not sure what this is called or how to even begin to Google it. Any pointers? Is this something feasible for a beginner to learn, or is it way more involved than I am anticipating? Am using Android Studio. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) using `addTextChangedListener` to `EditText` which will be called whenever user will input anything in the `EditText`